# Is buying E1 license then upgrading E1 license to premium license, cost the same as buying premium license from day one?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, licensing, power-platform

I have this question regarding Power Platform licensing; Is buying E1 license then upgrading E1 license to premium license, cost the same as buying premium license from day one? As in my case i am planning to buy business standard licenses for all our users who need to access power apps, then to upgrade it to premium for the related users who exceeds the 6,000 requests per 24 hours.. but not sure if upgrading E1 to Premium will add additional cost compared to buying Premium license from day one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft 365 and Office 365 plan options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/office-365-plan-options),
the Office 365 E1 - Enterprise Office plan costs $10.00 per user per month, while the Microsoft 365 Business Premium plan costs $22.00 per user per month. If you buy an E1 license and then upgrade it to a premium license, you would have to pay the difference of $12.00 per user per month for the remaining period of your subscription. However, if you buy a premium license from day one, you would pay $22.00 per user per month for the entire duration of your subscription.

Therefore, the total cost of buying an E1 license and then upgrading it to a premium license would depend on when you make the upgrade and how long your subscription lasts. For example, if you buy an E1 license for one year and then upgrade it to a premium license after six months, you would pay $10.00 x 6 + $22.00 x 6 = $192.00 per user for that year. However, if you buy a premium license from day one for one year, you would pay $22.00 x 12 = $264.00 per user for that year.